# Digitizing in GRASS GIS

Tags: coordinate-system, grass-gis, vector

I need to use GRASS GIS to digitize vectors and do further analysis.

Until now I only know how to import layers and change their characteristics (color). I want to create a square vector on the map so that I can do some simulations on it (e.g. to obtain a temperature map, ...).

I have four days to be an expert in GRASS GIS, if there is anyone who can help me I will gladly accept his help.

Comment: You want to create a new polygon? So something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqDLYPbkbxU ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Link provided above, there is a lot of information on the GRASS GIS website and Wiki. Please see [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/wxGUI.vdigit.html) regarding the digitizing GUI available in GRASS and this [link](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Vector_Digitizer) provides a very clear explanation of the Vector Digitising tools (see screenshot).

[image]

In addition, the GRASS GIS [Quickstart Manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/helptext.html) and the GRASS [First Time Users](https://grass.osgeo.org/documentation/first-time-users/) pages are also useful and cover many of the topics that face newcomers to the software.